# javascript "toggle effect with timeout" bugging because an "opacity:0"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I developed a small javascript to add a toggle effect to objects (Yes I know that jquery do this, but I don't want to load jquery for this).

I've done the following code:

```
function nice_toggling(button_id, container_id) {

    var container_div = document.getElementById(container_id)
    var left_margin = container_div.style.marginLeft

    // create the css classes so no extra css be necessary
    var css_clases = document.createElement('style');
    css_clases.type = 'text/css';
    css_clases.innerHTML = '.hidden1 {display: none;} .hidden2 {opacity: 0}';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css_clases);

    container_div.className = 'hidden1 hidden2'
    container_div.style.height= '0px'   

    // This avoids displaying the div
    setTimeout(function () {
        container_div.style.transition='all .10s linear'
    }, 50);


    document.getElementById(button_id).onclick=function () {
      if (container_div.className.indexOf('hidden1') > -1) {
         container_div.style.marginLeft= left_margin
        container_div.className = container_div.className.replace(/hidden1/g,'')
        setTimeout(function () {
          container_div.className = container_div.className.replace(/hidden2/g,'')
          container_div.style.height = 'auto'   
        }, 5);

      } else {
        container_div.className = container_div.className+' hidden2'        
        setTimeout(function () {
          container_div.className = container_div.className+' hidden1'
          setTimeout(function () {
            container_div.style.height= '0px'
            container_div.style.zIndex = '-1'
          }, 290);        
        }, 5);    
      }
    }   
    }
```

And it works good, except by the fact that on my website I'm using a div with links just after the container handled by the `nice_toggling` function. Because of this, it is not possible to click on the first link of the div.

I have recreated a minimal working example at [jsfinddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gw01s08t/3/)

The funny thing is that when I set `{opacity: 1}`, the code works fine! (but of course, we can see the "hidden text" )

I'd really like to understand why this code is not working, and if there is a better solution that just setting an opacity. I would like to avoid that the user clicks over a "hidden link".

I tried by setting a `margin-left: -1000px` but the code wasn't great, the "toggling effect" was kinda ugly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "overflow:hidden" to your hidden2 class. Even though the height is 0, the content is still overlap the container and overlap your links.

Answer (score 0):

Its not to do with overflow, your default css is overriding your hidden1 class

```
#rss-filters {display: block;}
```

That line is negating the hidden1 class added by your javascript.

Comment: The thing is that if you remove `#rss-filters {display: block;}` then the "transition effect" disappears!

Comment: I don't see that it does.  If I comment that out it works nicely:  https://jsfiddle.net/gw01s08t/4/  Either way, it looks live you've got it working. :-)

Comment: You can see it if you add more delay, take a look to the difference between [display "with block"](https://jsfiddle.net/gw01s08t/6/) and [with display "without block"](https://jsfiddle.net/gw01s08t/5/) (Click many times). Anyways thanks for trying to help :)